# How to POST a XML file using cURL?

Tags: xml, post, curl

I'm using a web interface that allows me to post stuff over a cURL request.

A sample post looks like this:

```
<status>A note</status>
```

But whenever I try to send this, it seems to not accept the XML

```
curl http://website.com/update -d '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><status>test</status>' -H 'Accept: application/xml' \ -H 'Content-Type: application/xml'  -u username:password
```

I can do any other type of requests, just sending this XML doesn't seem to work, am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [send/post xml file using curl command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007253/send-post-xml-file-using-curl-command-line)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To send data (xml,json,text,etc) using `curl` you have to use POST method and add `--data-urlencode` parameter, like shown bellow:

```
curl -X POST http://website.com/update \
  --data-urlencode xml="<status>A note</status>" \
  -H 'Accept: application/xml' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
  -u username:password
```

or

```
curl -X POST http://website.com/update \
  --data-urlencode "<status>A note</status>" \
  -H 'Accept: application/xml' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
  -u username:password
```

If you want to send via GET i think you have to encode the string before calling `curl` command

Comment: How to send xml attribute in curl request any ideas?

Comment: @gorp88 you could try one of these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880009/curl-sending-xml-incorrectly-when-using-tag-attributes
https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request

Comment: @flavio thank you, but I had resolved my issue using "\" escape character in xml string for attributes.